# How a failover in Active/Passive SAN multipath should be properly handled on Linux multipath system?

Tags: linux, storage-area-network, multipath, hpe, open-iscsi

I try to create a multipath configuration with SAN HPE EVA 6350 (2xHSV340 controllers with iSCSI mezzanines and FC/iSCSI multiplexers) and Linux debian 12 systems over iSCSI.

Vdisks created on EVA have an "owner" controller,I left all of them belonging to Controller 1. Targets presented by SAN have FC WWPN in its names so one can determine what FC path and controller is this target connected to. After login, only targets that are connected to Controller 1 FC adapter, give block devices (paths). So, when 4 iSCSI sessions are active, just 2 paths are present. Thus, multipath is never aware about ALL paths.

I rebooted SAN Controller 1 assuming that SAN will automatically re-route its vdisks to passive Controller 2. But no paths appeared automatically nor after re-login to these sessions. So I ended up with corrupted block i/o and multipath with just 2 faulted paths.

What is proper way to perform active-to-passive failover? Should some request be sent to SAN from initiator, or it's SAN internal task? Can Linux open-iscsi + multipath handle such a config properly at all?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your particular SAN device, but generally *both* controllers should present their LUNs using different WWPNs during discovery. It is then up to initiator to treat these as active/active or active/passive configuration, but all LUNs should be discovered on all redundant paths beforehand.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But actually I don't see paths (LUNs) from passive controller. The same behaviour with another SAN, Dell SC7020. I doubt that can be open-iscsi issue, but I can't find any info about this. Moreover, the same SAN (HPE EVA) has FC interfaces and there do exist FC paths from both controllers (multipath status active/enabled). But with its iSCSI situation is different...

Answer (score 4):

The back-end FC ports of each ISCSI module (also called as "MPX bridge" as it performs the role of ISCSI multiplexer from ISCSI to FC) on the EVA connects as a FC Direct Connect to HSV front-end FC ports on each HSV controller. AFAIK there are 2 backend FC ports for each ISCSI module and those ports each connect separately to controller A and B.

The multipath info for the LUN on the ISCSI initiator host must display all possible ISCSI paths from the ISCSI module(s) (i.e through both the HSV controllers), with paths to the Standby HSV controller for the LUN listed as "Standby", while the paths to the Active HSV controller for the LUN would be listed as "Active". The ISCSI target names from the ISCSI module(s)  should include the FC WWN's of all the HSV controller front-end FC ports that the ISCSI module is correctly configured for.

I don't have the privileges on this site to comment and ask more about your ISCSI module configuration as seen on the HPE EVA CommandView array management UI, so you may like to check on the following:

1. That the ISCSI Controllers properties are showing up as "good" status in the CommandView pages. ( Storage Network->Array->Hardware->ISCSI Devices->ISCSI Controller 1 and 2). In particular, check the back-end status of the "FC ports" and "Presented Targets" in the tabbed pages. Cross-check the FC port status as seen in this page against the actual HSV Array FC Controller port properties page.
2. That the ISCSI MPX Host (i.e the MultiPleXer Host which is automatically/internally created by CommandView in Array->Hosts) is showing up all the data correctly on it's pages in CommandView. Each MPX Host should be seeing the requisite number of HSV controller FC front-end ports of the EVA as configured and make sure to check that those FC connections to the HSV FC ports are online.
3. That your initiator host is correctly configured as a Linux host in CommandView.

If the EVA vdisk's HSV controller ownership (as seen in CommandView) changes to the other HSV controller when you shutdown or reboot the owning controller, then it could be an issue with the ISCSI module(s) configuration on the EVA.

If the ISCSI module(s) configuration is determined to be all right, you may like to check if the problem occurs with a Windows Server host? If there is no issue seen on Windows, then either the Linux multipath configuration is not correct or the Linux multipathing through ISCSI to the EVA may not be supported by HPE. If it is indeed supported by HPE, check that the Linux initiator host's **multipath.conf** file is correctly configured as per the *HPE EVA Device Mapper multipath.conf recommendations for Linux*.

To answer your other question, multipath software/drivers on the hosts in a SAN handle the failover and failback of paths to a LUN. The actual multipath configuration on the host depends on the vendor's storage system capability - whether the storage system's controllers are active/active, active/standby or active/passive. The EVA is an active/standby storage array and it is compliant with the SCSI ALUA standard for such systems. SCSI commands from the initiator host's multipathing drivers are sent to the array's target ports via the available/online paths to determine which paths are active and which paths are standby.